# Class scheduling tool with image output

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, image, multiprocessing

I have a multilayered dictionary that contains information about classes. I am using this to code an automatic schedule builder that I will eventually add to a separate Tkinter application I made that contains similar programs.

I spent a lot of time streamlining the code and improving its performance. When I started writing the code it took over an hour to load a few sections, now I can load 5 whole classes in a little less than 5 minutes, which was a relief to me as a scheduler that takes hours for a few sections is not useful at all. The main reason it takes so long is due to the fact that saving an image using PIL takes about 0.7 seconds per save and the process I use to build the image used to take 10 seconds but now takes about 0.5 seconds, making the total process 1.4 seconds per image, which really isn't that bad, but when you make 100 images it does take an uncomfortably long time. Now I can't think of any way of lowering this time any farther.

**The area that takes the most time (Not including the image saving area which, again, takes 0.7 seconds per image) :**

I used multiprocessing and itertools to speed up the process, taking the time needed to find overlaps from an hour to around 30 seconds, but it is still a but slow. When working with a lot of possibilities, usually in the hundreds of thousands, the following code takes 20-40 seconds to go through on a good day. Is there any way to make this run faster/more efficiently? (Side note, I have found that the more frequent I run the program, the quicker it runs through the code, like from 35 seconds to 24 seconds... could this have something to do with the cores being more malleable the more frequently they are used?)

```
    cores = mp.cpu_count()

    splitSchedules = chunkify(PossibleSchedules, cores)

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=cores)
    result = pool.map(removeOverlaps, splitSchedules)

    TruePossibleSchedules = []
    for x in range(cores):
        TruePossibleSchedules = TruePossibleSchedules + result[x]

    TruePossibleSchedules.sort()
    sortedTruePossibleSchedules = list(TruePossibleSchedules for TruePossibleSchedules,_ in itertools.groupby(TruePossibleSchedules))

def chunkify(lst,n):
    return [ lst[i::n] for i in xrange(n) ]


def removeOverlaps(PossibleSchedules):

    first = False
    if PossibleSchedules[-1] == "First":
        cores = mp.cpu_count()
        print "Commandeering your %s cores..."%(cores)
        del PossibleSchedules[-1]
        first = True

    TruePossibleSchedules = []
    if first:
        for schedule in range(0, len(PossibleSchedules)):
            overlapping = [[s,e] for s in PossibleSchedules[schedule] for x in s for e in PossibleSchedules[schedule] for y in e  if s is not e and x[2]==y[2] and (int(x[0])<=int(y[1]) and int(x[1])>=int(y[0]))]

            good = True
            if overlapping:
                good = False
            if good:
                TruePossibleSchedules.append(PossibleSchedules[schedule])

            sys.stdout.write("\rCalculating real schedules: " + str( float("{0:.2f}".format(( float(schedule+1)/float(len(PossibleSchedules))) *100) )) + "%    ")
            sys.stdout.flush()

        sys.stdout.write("\rThanks for letting me borrow those      ")
        sys.stdout.flush()
    else:
        for schedule in range(0, len(PossibleSchedules)):
            overlapping = [[s,e] for s in PossibleSchedules[schedule] for x in s for e in PossibleSchedules[schedule] for y in e  if s is not e and x[2]==y[2] and (int(x[0])<=int(y[1]) and int(x[1])>=int(y[0]))]

            good = True
            if overlapping:
                good = False
            if good:
                TruePossibleSchedules.append(PossibleSchedules[schedule])

    return TruePossibleSchedules
```

## Full code:

Referenced picture used:
[Schedule Grid.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdx5w.png)

[Database used to pull information](https://web.stevens.edu/scheduler/core/2017F/2017F.xml)

```
# coding: utf-8
'''
Created on Jul 31, 2017

@author: Jake
This is a bit sloppy and unorganized, I am still working on it and it is not going to be stand alone, it will be put into a Tkinter application I made.

'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import urllib
import shlex
import re
import time
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import itertools
import os
import shutil
import colorsys
import copy
import random
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys

class Vars():

    global vari
    vari = {}

    def GetVars(self, var):

        return vari.get(str(var))

    def SendVars(self, var, val):

        vari[str(var)] = val


runStart = time.time()

# Fluid Dynamics is a little ducked, it has multiple different section numbers, so if you want CHE, CE, or ME Fluid Mechanics then do not add it as this will not produce a correct result.

designators = {
    "CC": "Co-Req required ",
    "CS": "Freshman quiz/ Next Class ",
    "CA": "Activity needed ",
    "RQ": "Pre-Req required ",
    "R&": "Pre-Req required ",
    "RQM": "Pre-Req course reqd w/ min grade ",
    "RM&": "(cont.) Pre-Req reqd w/ min grade ",
    "RQT": "Pre-Req test required ",
    "RT&": "(cont.) Pre-Req test required ",
    "NQ": "Pre-Req course required ",
    "N&": "Pre-Req course required ",
    "NQM": "Concur Pre-Req reqd w/ min grade ",
    "NM&": "(cont.) Concur Pre-Req w/ min grade ",
    "MB": "By Application Only ",
    "MP": "Pre-Req Required ",
    "MC": "Co-Req Required ",
    "ML": "Lab Fee Required ",
    "MA": "Permission of Advisor Required ",
    "MI": "Permission of Instructor Required ",
    "MH": "Department Head Approval Required ",
    "MN": "No Credit Course for Departmental Majors ",
    "MS": "Studio course; No general Humanities credit ",
    "PAU": "Auditors need instructor permission ",
    "PCG": "Permission needed from Continuing ED ",
    "PDP": "Permission needed from department ",
    "PIN": "Permission needed from instructor ",
    "PUN": "Undergrads need instructor permission ",
    "PUA": "UGs need permission of Dean of UG Academics ",    
    "LEC": "lecture",
    "L/L": "lecture/lab",
    "LAB": "laboratory",
    "PSI": "personalized self-paced instruction",
    "QUZ": "quiz",
    "RCT": "recitation",
    "SEM": "seminar",
    "PRA": "practicum",
    "HSG": "housing (dorm)",
    "MCE": "Multiple Course Entry base course",
    "WSP": "Work Shop"
}
if os.path.exists((os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/Schedules")):
    shutil.rmtree((os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/Schedules"))

if not os.path.exists((os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/Schedules")): 
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/Schedules")

ScheduleGrid = Image.open('Schedule Grid.png').convert('RGBA')
ClassBlocks = Image.new('RGBA', ScheduleGrid.size, (255,255,255,0))
out = Image.alpha_composite(ScheduleGrid, ClassBlocks)
out.save("Schedule.png")

h = HTMLParser()
page = urllib.urlopen('https://web.stevens.edu/scheduler/core/2017F/2017F.xml').read() # Get to database
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

while True:
    try:
        RawClassData = soup.contents[10].contents[0].contents[0].contents
        break
    except:
        print 'Trying again'

classes = {}
backupClasses = {}
selectedClasses = {}
var = Vars()
var.SendVars("color", 30)
def makeDatabase():


    for i in range(0, len(RawClassData)): # Parse through each class

        sys.stdout.write("\rLoading classes: " + str( float("{0:.2f}".format(( float(i)/float(len(RawClassData))) *100) )) + "%      ")
        sys.stdout.flush()

        try:
            ClassDict = {}
            MeetingsDict = {}
            RequirementsDict = {}


            #For meetings
            numMeetings = str(RawClassData[i]).split().count("<meeting")
            seper = str(RawClassData[i]).split("meeting") # Split string by meeting to get subject name and value
            try:
                for line in range(0, len(seper)):
                    if seper[line] == ">\n<":
                        del seper[line]
            except:
                pass
            for x in range(0, numMeetings):
                subMeetingsDict = {}
                MeetingInfo = shlex.split(h.unescape(str(seper[x+1]).replace(">", " "))) # sort into a list grouping string in quotes and getting rid of unnecessary symbols 

                for item in MeetingInfo: # Go through list of meeting info
                    try:

                        thing = item.split("=") # Split string by = to get subject name and value
                        name = thing[0]
                        if any(char.isdigit() for char in thing[1]): # Get rid of annoying Z at the end of numbers
                            for char in thing[1]:
                                if "-" == char:
                                    thing[1] = re.sub("[Z]","",thing[1])
                                    break

                        value = re.sub(' +',' ', thing[1])
                        if value:   # If subject has a value, store it
                            try:
                                subMeetingsDict[str(name)] = str(designators[str(value)])  # Store value converted to designator in a dictionary with the subject as the key
                            except KeyError:
                                subMeetingsDict[str(name)] = str(value)  # Store value in a dictionary with the subject as the key
                    except:
                        pass

                MeetingsDict["meeting" + str(x)] = subMeetingsDict
            ClassDict["meetings"] = MeetingsDict

            #For requirements
            numRequirements = str(RawClassData[i]).split().count("<requirement")
            seper = str(RawClassData[i]).split("requirement") # Split string by requirements to get subject name and value
            try:
                for line in range(0, len(seper) - 1):
                    if seper[line] == ">\n<":
                        del seper[line]
            except:
                pass
            for x in range(0, numRequirements):
                subRequirementsDict = {}
                RequirementsInfo = shlex.split(h.unescape(str(seper[-2 - x]).replace(">", " "))) # sort into a list grouping string in quotes and getting rid of unnecessary symbols 

                for item in RequirementsInfo: # Go through list of meeting info
                    try:

                        thing = item.split("=") # Split string by = to get subject name and value
                        name = thing[0]
                        if any(char.isdigit() for char in thing[1]): # Get rid of annoying Z at the end of numbers
                            for char in thing[1]:
                                if "-" == char:
                                    thing[1] = re.sub("[Z]","",thing[1])
                                    break

                        value = re.sub(' +',' ', thing[1])
                        if value:   # If subject has a value, store it
                            try:
                                subRequirementsDict[str(name)] = str(designators[str(value)])  # Store value converted to designator in a dictionary with the subject as the key
                            except KeyError:
                                subRequirementsDict[str(name)] = str(value)  # Store value in a dictionary with the subject as the key
                    except:
                        pass

                RequirementsDict["requirement" + str(x)] = subRequirementsDict
            ClassDict["requirements"] = RequirementsDict


            AllCourseInfo = shlex.split(h.unescape(str(RawClassData[i]).replace(">", " "))) # sort into a list grouping string in quotes and getting rid of unnecessary symbols 


            for item in AllCourseInfo: # Go through list of class info
                try:

                    thing = item.split("=") # Split string by = to get subject name and value
                    name = thing[0]
                    if any(char.isdigit() for char in thing[1]): # Get rid of annoying Z at the end of numbers
                        for char in thing[1]:
                            if "-" == char:
                                thing[1] = re.sub("[Z]","",thing[1])
                                break

                    value = re.sub(' +',' ', thing[1])
                    if value:   # If subject has a value, store it
                        try:
                            ClassDict[str(name)] = str(designators[str(value)])  # Store value converted to designator in a dictionary with the subject as the key
                        except KeyError:
                            ClassDict[str(name)] = str(value)  # Store value in a dictionary with the subject as the key
                except:
                    pass

            classes[str(ClassDict["section"])] = ClassDict
        except Exception:
            #logging.exception("message")
            pass
    sys.stdout.write("\rLoading classes: Done   ")
    sys.stdout.flush()

def printDic():
    with open("Classes", "w") as f:
        for key in classes:
            f.write("\n-------------%s------------" %key)
            for classkey in classes[key]:
                f.write( "\n%s : %s" %(classkey, classes[key][classkey]))
            f.write("\n")

def printSection(selection):
    print "\n-------------%s------------" %selection
    for classkey in classes[selection]:
        print "%s : %s" %(classkey, classes[selection][classkey])

def printClass(selection):

    prntSel = True

    for key in classes:
        if classes[key]["title"] == selection:
            prntSel = False
            print "\n-------------%s------------" %key
            for classkey in classes[key]:
                print "%s : %s" %(classkey, classes[key][classkey])
    if prntSel:
        print "\n-------------%s------------" %selection
        for classkey in classes[selection]:
            print "%s : %s" %(classkey, classes[selection][classkey])

        #Backup classes if section closed
        for key in classes:  
            if (classes[key]["title"] == classes[selection]["title"]) and (classes[key] != classes[selection]):
                print "\n-----Backup--------%s------------" %key
                for classkey in classes[key]:
                    print "%s : %s" %(classkey, classes[key][classkey])

def printSelectedClasses():

    for key in selectedClasses:
        print "\n-------------%s------------" %key
        for classkey in selectedClasses[key]:
            print "%s : %s" %(classkey, selectedClasses[key][classkey])

def pickClass(selection):

    oneSel = True
    classToSort = {}
    var = Vars()
    colorStep = var.GetVars("color")

    for key in classes:
        ClassDict = {}
        if classes[key]["title"] == selection:
            repeat = False
            oneSel = False
            for classkey in classes[key]:
                ClassDict[str(classkey)] = classes[key][classkey]
            for selectedClass in selectedClasses:
                for section in selectedClasses[selectedClass]:
                    if ClassDict["activity"] == selectedClasses[selectedClass][section]["activity"] and ClassDict["title"] == selectedClasses[selectedClass][section]["title"]:
                        repeat = True

            if  repeat == False:
                ClassDict["variable"] = "True"
                h, l, s = colorStep, 50, 100
                r, g, b = colorsys.hls_to_rgb(h/360.0, l/100.0, s/100.0)
                r, g, b = [x*255 for x in r, g, b]
                ClassDict["color"] = int(r),int(g),int(b)  # Changing color
                classToSort[str(ClassDict["section"])] = ClassDict    #Put selected class in a dictionary
                classes[str(ClassDict["section"])] = ClassDict


    if oneSel:
        classToSort[str(classes[selection]["section"])] = classes[selection]    #Put selected section in a dictionary
        classToSort[str(classes[selection]["section"])]["variable"] = "False"  #Not changing

        # Add activities
        activityHeads = ["LEC", "PRA", "L/L", "SEM", "PSI", "WSP"]
        for activityType in activityHeads:
            if str(classes[selection]["activity"]) == designators[str(activityType)]:
                Quiz = False
                Activity = False
                for requirement in classes[selection]["requirements"]:
                    for requirementInfo in classes[selection]["requirements"][requirement]:
                        # Add required activities
                        if str(classes[selection]["requirements"][requirement][requirementInfo]) == "Activity needed ":
                                Activity = True
                        # Add Recitation
                        if Activity == True and ("recitation" in str(classes[selection]["requirements"][requirement][requirementInfo])):
                            isRecIn = False
                            RecDic = {}
                            for recitSection in classes:
                                if classes[recitSection]["title"] == classes[selection]["title"]:
                                    if classes[recitSection]["activity"] == "recitation":
                                        RecDic[str(classes[recitSection]["section"])] = classes[recitSection]
                                        RecDic[str(classes[recitSection]["section"])]["variable"] = "True"  # Changing
                                        h, l, s = colorStep, 50, 100
                                        r, g, b = colorsys.hls_to_rgb(h/360.0, l/100.0, s/100.0)
                                        r, g, b = [x*255 for x in r, g, b]
                                        RecDic[str(classes[recitSection]["section"])]["color"] = int(r),int(g),int(b)  # Changing color
                            for selectedClassTitle in selectedClasses:
                                for selectedClass in selectedClasses[selectedClassTitle]:
                                    for selectedRec in RecDic:
                                        if selectedClasses[selectedClassTitle][selectedClass] == RecDic[selectedRec]:
                                            isRecIn = True
                            if isRecIn == False: # Only adds recitation if a recitation not is already given.
                                classToSort.update(RecDic)    
                                ''' Add this functionality for when a title is given'''
                        # Add Lab
                        if Activity == True and ("laboratory" in str(classes[selection]["requirements"][requirement][requirementInfo])):
                            isLabIn = False
                            LabDic = {}
                            for labSection in classes:
                                if classes[labSection]["title"] == classes[selection]["title"]:
                                    if classes[labSection]["activity"] == "laboratory":
                                        LabDic[str(classes[labSection]["section"])] = classes[labSection]
                                        LabDic[str(classes[labSection]["section"])]["variable"] = "True"  # Changing
                                        h, l, s = colorStep, 50, 100
                                        r, g, b = colorsys.hls_to_rgb(h/360.0, l/100.0, s/100.0)
                                        r, g, b = [x*255 for x in r, g, b]
                                        LabDic[str(classes[labSection]["section"])]["color"] = int(r),int(g),int(b)  # Changing color
                            for selectedClassTitle in selectedClasses:
                                for selectedClass in selectedClasses[selectedClassTitle]:
                                    for selectedRec in LabDic:
                                        if selectedClasses[selectedClassTitle][selectedClass] == LabDic[selectedRec]:
                                            isLabIn = True
                            if isLabIn == False: # Only adds recitation if a recitation not is already given.
                                classToSort.update(LabDic)    # Add this functionality for when a title is given

        #Backup classes if section closed
        for key in classes:  
            ClassDict = {}
            if (classes[key]["title"] == classes[selection]["title"]) and (classes[key] != classes[selection]):
                for classkey in classes[key]:
                    ClassDict[str(classkey)] = classes[key][classkey]
                backupClasses[str(ClassDict["section"])] = ClassDict    #Put extra sections with the same title in a dictionary

    if classToSort:
        var.SendVars("color", colorStep + 30)
        activities = ["LEC", "L/L", "LAB", "PSI", "QUZ", "RCT", "SEM", "PRA", "HSG", "MCE", "WSP"]
        activitiesDict = {"LEC": {}, "L/L": {}, "LAB": {}, "PSI": {}, "QUZ": {}, "RCT": {}, "SEM": {}, "PRA": {}, "HSG": {}, "MCE": {}, "WSP": {}}

        for activity in activities:
            for key in classToSort:
                ClassDict = {}
                if classToSort[key]["activity"] == designators[str(activity)]:
                    for classkey in classToSort[key]:
                        ClassDict[str(classkey)] = classToSort[key][classkey]
                    activitiesDict[activity][str(ClassDict["section"])] = ClassDict    #Put selected class section in a dictionary

        #"CS": "Freshman quiz/ Next Class "
        #"CA": "Activity needed ",   
        # LEC, PRA, L/L, SEM, PSI, WSP are the only ones that need to look for CS and CA
        activityHeads = ["LEC", "PRA", "L/L", "SEM", "PSI", "WSP"]

        # Build dictionary to add to selectedClasses
        for actClass in activitiesDict:
            if actClass:
                for classSec in activitiesDict[actClass]:
                    selectedClasses[ str(activitiesDict[actClass][classSec]["title"]) + " " + str(activitiesDict[actClass][classSec]["activity"])] = activitiesDict[actClass] # Add all activities of each class

                    # Add Freshman Quiz's
                    for key in activityHeads:
                        Quiz = False
                        for requirement in activitiesDict[actClass][classSec]["requirements"]:
                            for requirementInfo in activitiesDict[actClass][classSec]["requirements"][requirement]:
                                if str(activitiesDict[actClass][classSec]["requirements"][requirement][requirementInfo]) == "Freshman quiz/ Next Class ":
                                    Quiz = True
                                if Quiz == True and ("D 110" in str(activitiesDict[actClass][classSec]["requirements"][requirement][requirementInfo])):
                                    quiz = {}
                                    quiz[ str(activitiesDict[actClass][classSec]["requirements"][requirement][requirementInfo]) ] = classes[str(activitiesDict[actClass][classSec]["requirements"][requirement][requirementInfo])]
                                    quiz[ str(activitiesDict[actClass][classSec]["requirements"][requirement][requirementInfo]) ]["variable"] = "False"  #Not changing
                                    selectedClasses[ str(activitiesDict[actClass][classSec]["title"]) + " Quiz " + str(activitiesDict[actClass][classSec]["requirements"][requirement][requirementInfo])[-1] ] = quiz # Add freshman quiz


def CreateScheduleImage(possibleSchedules):
    try:
        startTest = time.time() # Start timeing the test
        scheduleNum = 0
        if len(possibleSchedules) > 3:
            for x in range(2):
                schedule = possibleSchedules[0]
                ScheduleGrid = Image.open('Schedule.png').convert('RGBA')
                ClassBlocks = Image.new('RGBA', ScheduleGrid.size, (255,255,255,0))
                fnt = ImageFont.truetype('Library/Fonts/Tahoma.ttf', 8*2)
                fnt2 = ImageFont.truetype('Library/Fonts/Tahoma.ttf', 7*2)
                d = ImageDraw.Draw(ClassBlocks)
                for section in schedule:
                    meetings = schedule[section]["meetings"]
                    for meeting in meetings:
                        days = schedule[str(section)]["meetings"][str(meeting)]["day"]
                        for day in days:
                            cltimeS = schedule[section]["meetings"][meeting]["starttime"]
                            cltimeF = schedule[section]["meetings"][meeting]["endtime"]
                            classStart = (cltimeS.split(":"))
                            del classStart[-1]
                            starttime = ( (int(classStart[0]) - 8)*60 + int(classStart[1]))/15 *19
                            classEnd = (cltimeF.split(":"))
                            del classEnd[-1]
                            endtime = ( (int(classEnd[0]) - 8)*60 + int(classEnd[1]))/15 *19 - starttime
                            if day == "M":
                                dayNum = 0
                            elif day == "T":
                                dayNum = 1
                            elif day == "W":
                                dayNum = 2
                            elif day == "R":
                                dayNum = 3
                            elif day == "F":
                                dayNum = 4
                            x1 = 80 + (190 + 1)*dayNum
                            y1 = 32 + starttime + (16*19) #Add 4 hours because weird bug
                            x2 = x1 + 190
                            y2 = y1 + endtime
                            BoxPosition = [((x1 +2)*2, (y1 +2)*2), ((x2)*2), ((y2 -1)*2)]
                            BoxOutlinePosition1 = [((x1 +1.5)*2, (y1 +1.5)*2), ((x2+0.5)*2), ((y2 - 0.5)*2)]
                            BoxOutlinePosition2 = [((x1 +1)*2, (y1 +1)*2), ((x2+1)*2), ((y2)*2)]
                            d.rectangle(BoxOutlinePosition2, fill=(90,190,120,0), outline="darkred")
                            d.rectangle(BoxOutlinePosition1, fill=(90,190,120,0), outline="grey")
                            if schedule[section]["variable"] == "False":
                                d.rectangle(BoxPosition, fill=(90,190,120,180), outline="darkred")
                            else:
                                d.rectangle(BoxPosition, fill=(schedule[section]["color"] + (180,)), outline="darkred")
                            d.text([(x1 + 5)*2, (y1 + 1 +9*1)*2], schedule[section]["title"], font=fnt, fill=(0,0,0,255))
                            d.text([(x1 + 5)*2, (y1 + 1)*2], schedule[section]["section"], font=fnt, fill=(0,0,0,255))
                            d.text([(x1 + 5)*2, (y1 + 1 +9*2)*2], schedule[section]["instructor1"], font=fnt, fill=(0,0,0,255))
                            d.text([(x1 + 5)*2, (y1 + 1 +9*3)*2], schedule[section]["callnumber"], font=fnt, fill=(0,0,0,255))
                            requirements = schedule[section]["requirements"]
                            count = 1
                            for requirement in requirements:
                                control = str(schedule[section]["requirements"][requirement]["control"])
                                values = []
                                for x in range(0, str(schedule[section]["requirements"][requirement]).count("value")):
                                    values.append(str(schedule[section]["requirements"][requirement]["value" + str(x + 1)]))
                                if values:
                                    msg = control + ": " + str(values)
                                else:
                                    msg = control
                                width, height = d.textsize(msg)
                                y2 = y2 -5
                                d.text([(x2)*2 - width-10, (y2 -(height-5)*count)*2], msg, font=fnt2, fill=(200,0,0,255))
                                count = count + 0.5
                out = Image.alpha_composite(ScheduleGrid, ClassBlocks)
                out.save((os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/Schedules/Schedule" + str(scheduleNum) + ".png") )
                print "Preparing..."
                scheduleNum = scheduleNum + 1     #
            endTest = time.time()   # End timing the test

            if os.path.exists((os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/Schedules")):
                shutil.rmtree((os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/Schedules"))
            if not os.path.exists((os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/Schedules")): 
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/Schedules")
            photoTime = (endTest - startTest)/2
        else:
            photoTime = 1.4

        scheduleNum = 0
        estimate = str( (len(possibleSchedules)*photoTime) / 60).split(".")


        print "\n\nEstimated time to load %s images: %s minutes and %s seconds"%(len(possibleSchedules), int(estimate[0]), float("." + estimate[1])*60 )
        sys.stdout.write("\rTime left " + str( float("{0:.2f}".format((len(possibleSchedules))*photoTime - scheduleNum*photoTime)) ) + " seconds     ")
        sys.stdout.flush()

        startPhotos = time.time()
        for schedule in possibleSchedules:
            ScheduleGrid = Image.open('Schedule.png').convert('RGBA')
            ClassBlocks = Image.new('RGBA', ScheduleGrid.size, (255,255,255,0))
            fnt = ImageFont.truetype('Library/Fonts/Tahoma.ttf', 8*2)
            fnt2 = ImageFont.truetype('Library/Fonts/Tahoma.ttf', 7*2)
            d = ImageDraw.Draw(ClassBlocks)

            for section in schedule:
                meetings = schedule[section]["meetings"]
                for meeting in meetings:
                    days = schedule[str(section)]["meetings"][str(meeting)]["day"]
                    for day in days:

                        cltimeS = schedule[section]["meetings"][meeting]["starttime"]
                        cltimeF = schedule[section]["meetings"][meeting]["endtime"]

                        classStart = (cltimeS.split(":"))
                        del classStart[-1]
                        starttime = ( (int(classStart[0]) - 8)*60 + int(classStart[1]))/15 *19


                        classEnd = (cltimeF.split(":"))
                        del classEnd[-1]
                        endtime = ( (int(classEnd[0]) - 8)*60 + int(classEnd[1]))/15 *19 - starttime

                        if day == "M":
                            dayNum = 0
                        elif day == "T":
                            dayNum = 1
                        elif day == "W":
                            dayNum = 2
                        elif day == "R":
                            dayNum = 3
                        elif day == "F":
                            dayNum = 4

                        x1 = 80 + (190 + 1)*dayNum
                        y1 = 32 + starttime + (16*19) #Add 4 hours because weird bug
                        x2 = x1 + 190
                        y2 = y1 + endtime

                        BoxPosition = [((x1 +2)*2, (y1 +2)*2), ((x2)*2), ((y2 -1)*2)]
                        BoxOutlinePosition1 = [((x1 +1.5)*2, (y1 +1.5)*2), ((x2+0.5)*2), ((y2 - 0.5)*2)]
                        BoxOutlinePosition2 = [((x1 +1)*2, (y1 +1)*2), ((x2+1)*2), ((y2)*2)]
                        # draw text, half opacity
                        d.rectangle(BoxOutlinePosition2, fill=(90,190,120,0), outline="darkred")
                        d.rectangle(BoxOutlinePosition1, fill=(90,190,120,0), outline="grey")
                        if schedule[section]["variable"] == "False":
                            d.rectangle(BoxPosition, fill=(90,190,120,180), outline="darkred")
                        else:
                            d.rectangle(BoxPosition, fill=(schedule[section]["color"] + (180,)), outline="darkred")
                        # draw text, full opacity
                        d.text([(x1 + 5)*2, (y1 + 1 +9*1)*2], schedule[section]["title"], font=fnt, fill=(0,0,0,255))
                        d.text([(x1 + 5)*2, (y1 + 1)*2], schedule[section]["section"], font=fnt, fill=(0,0,0,255))
                        d.text([(x1 + 5)*2, (y1 + 1 +9*2)*2], schedule[section]["instructor1"], font=fnt, fill=(0,0,0,255))
                        d.text([(x1 + 5)*2, (y1 + 1 +9*3)*2], schedule[section]["callnumber"], font=fnt, fill=(0,0,0,255))

                        #Print out required classes to bottom right corner in red

                        requirements = schedule[section]["requirements"]
                        count = 1
                        for requirement in requirements:

                            control = str(schedule[section]["requirements"][requirement]["control"])

                            values = []
                            for x in range(0, str(schedule[section]["requirements"][requirement]).count("value")):
                                values.append(str(schedule[section]["requirements"][requirement]["value" + str(x + 1)]))

                            if values:
                                msg = control + ": " + str(values)
                            else:
                                msg = control

                            width, height = d.textsize(msg)
                            y2 = y2 -5
                            d.text([(x2)*2 - width-10, (y2 -(height-5)*count)*2], msg, font=fnt2, fill=(200,0,0,255))

                            count = count + 0.5

            out = Image.alpha_composite(ScheduleGrid, ClassBlocks)

            #timeToSave = time.time()         
            out.save((os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/Schedules/Schedule" + str(scheduleNum) + ".png") )  # Takes about 0.75 sec to save
            #print "Time to save photo" + str(time.time() - timeToSave)   

            sys.stdout.write("\rLoading schedules: " + str( float("{0:.2f}".format(( float(scheduleNum+1)/float(len(possibleSchedules))) *100) )) + "%    ")
            sys.stdout.flush()

            '''sys.stdout.write("\rTime left " + str( float("{0:.2f}".format((len(possibleSchedules)-1)*photoTime - scheduleNum*photoTime)) ) + " seconds")
            sys.stdout.flush()'''
            scheduleNum = scheduleNum + 1     # Takes about 1.4 sec per photo

        print "\n\nEstimated time to load %s images: %s minutes and %s seconds"%(len(possibleSchedules), int(estimate[0]), float("." + estimate[1])*60 )
        actual = str( (time.time() - startPhotos) / 60).split(".")
        print "Actual time to load %s images: %s minutes and %s seconds"%(len(possibleSchedules), int(actual[0]), float("." + actual[1])*60 )
        print "Diff = " + str( abs((time.time() - startPhotos) - (len(possibleSchedules)*photoTime)) ) + " seconds"
        print "Error in guess = " + str(  float("{0:.2f}".format(((abs((time.time() - startPhotos) - (len(possibleSchedules)*photoTime))) / (time.time() - startPhotos)) * 100 )) ) + "%" + "\n\n"
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Bye"


def possibleCombos(ClassDic):

    try:
        AllClasses = []
        SectionMeetingTimes = []

        startSchedules = time.time()

        condencedClassTimeDic = {}
        ignore = {}

        for classType in ClassDic:
            condenceSectionDic = {}
            for section in ClassDic[classType]:
                for otherMeeting in ClassDic[classType][section]["meetings"]:
                    for meeting in ClassDic[classType][section]["meetings"]:
                        notIn = True
                        if (ClassDic[classType][section]["meetings"][meeting] != ClassDic[classType][section]["meetings"][otherMeeting]) and (ClassDic[classType][section]["meetings"][meeting]["starttime"] == ClassDic[classType][section]["meetings"][otherMeeting]["starttime"]) and (ClassDic[classType][section]["meetings"][meeting]["endtime"] == ClassDic[classType][section]["meetings"][otherMeeting]["endtime"]):
                            for alreadyIn in ignore:
                                if ignore[alreadyIn] == ClassDic[classType][section]["meetings"][otherMeeting]:
                                    notIn = False
                            if notIn:
                                ignore[str(ClassDic[classType][section]["meetings"])] = copy.deepcopy(ClassDic[classType][section]["meetings"][meeting])
                                ignore[str(ClassDic[classType][section]["section"])] = copy.deepcopy(ClassDic[classType][section])
                                sectionDay = str(ClassDic[classType][section]["meetings"][meeting]["day"]) + str(str(ClassDic[classType][section]["meetings"][otherMeeting]["day"]))
                                sectionName = str(ClassDic[classType][section]["section"])
                                condenceSectionDic[sectionName] = copy.deepcopy(ClassDic[classType][section])
                                meetingsDic = {}
                                meetingsDic[str(meeting)] = copy.deepcopy(ClassDic[classType][section]["meetings"][meeting])
                                meetingsDic[meeting]["day"] = sectionDay
                                condenceSectionDic[sectionName]["meetings"] = meetingsDic


            for section in ClassDic[classType]:
                notIn = True
                for alreadyIn in ignore:
                    if ignore[alreadyIn] == ClassDic[classType][section]:
                        notIn = False
                if notIn:
                    condenceSectionDic[str(ClassDic[classType][section]["section"])] = copy.deepcopy(ClassDic[classType][section])

            condencedClassTimeDic[str(classType)] = copy.deepcopy(condenceSectionDic)



        condencedClassDic = {}
        condencedSectionListDic = {}
        ignore = {}

        for classType in condencedClassTimeDic:
            condenceSectionDic = {}
            for section in condencedClassTimeDic[classType]:
                for otherSection in condencedClassTimeDic[classType]:
                    notIn = True
                    if (condencedClassTimeDic[classType][section] != condencedClassTimeDic[classType][otherSection]) and (condencedClassTimeDic[classType][section]["meetings"]["meeting0"]["starttime"] == condencedClassTimeDic[classType][otherSection]["meetings"]["meeting0"]["starttime"]) and (condencedClassTimeDic[classType][section]["meetings"]["meeting0"]["endtime"] == condencedClassTimeDic[classType][otherSection]["meetings"]["meeting0"]["endtime"]) and (condencedClassTimeDic[classType][section]["meetings"]["meeting0"]["day"] == condencedClassTimeDic[classType][otherSection]["meetings"]["meeting0"]["day"]) and (condencedClassTimeDic[classType][section]["activity"] == condencedClassTimeDic[classType][otherSection]["activity"]):
                        for alreadyIn in ignore:
                            if ignore[alreadyIn] == condencedClassTimeDic[classType][section]:
                                notIn = False
                        if notIn:
                            ignore[str(condencedClassTimeDic[classType][section])] = condencedClassTimeDic[classType][otherSection]
                            sectionName = str(condencedClassTimeDic[classType][section]["section"]) + "/" + str(((str(condencedClassTimeDic[classType][otherSection]["section"]).split(" "))[1][3:]))
                            sectionProf = str(condencedClassTimeDic[classType][section]["instructor1"]) + "/" + str(str(condencedClassTimeDic[classType][otherSection]["instructor1"]))
                            sectionNum = str(condencedClassTimeDic[classType][section]["callnumber"]) + "/" + str(str(condencedClassTimeDic[classType][otherSection]["callnumber"]))
                            condenceSectionDic[sectionName] = condencedClassTimeDic[classType][section]
                            condenceSectionDic[sectionName]["section"] = sectionName
                            condenceSectionDic[sectionName]["instructor1"] = sectionProf
                            condenceSectionDic[sectionName]["callnumber"] = sectionNum
                            condencedSectionListDic[sectionName] = condencedClassTimeDic[classType][section]
                            condencedSectionListDic[sectionName]["section"] = sectionName
                            condencedSectionListDic[sectionName]["instructor1"] = sectionProf
                            condencedSectionListDic[sectionName]["callnumber"] = sectionNum

            for section in condencedClassTimeDic[classType]:
                notIn = True
                for alreadyIn in ignore:
                    if ignore[alreadyIn] == condencedClassTimeDic[classType][section]:
                        notIn = False
                if notIn:
                    condenceSectionDic[str(condencedClassTimeDic[classType][section]["section"])] = condencedClassTimeDic[classType][section]
                    condencedSectionListDic[str(condencedClassTimeDic[classType][section]["section"])] = condencedClassTimeDic[classType][section]

            condencedClassDic[str(classType)] = condenceSectionDic


        # Create list of All classes
        for classToAdd in condencedClassDic:

            ClassTimes = []
            for classSection in condencedClassDic[classToAdd]:

                meetings = condencedClassDic[classToAdd][classSection]["meetings"]

                SectionMeetingTimes = []
                overlap = False
                for meeting in meetings:
                    days = condencedClassDic[classToAdd][classSection]["meetings"][str(meeting)]["day"]
                    for day in days:

                        cltimeS = condencedClassDic[classToAdd][classSection]["meetings"][meeting]["starttime"]
                        cltimeF = condencedClassDic[classToAdd][classSection]["meetings"][meeting]["endtime"]

                        classStart = (cltimeS.split(":"))
                        del classStart[-1]
                        starttime = ( str(classStart[0]) + str(classStart[1]) ) 


                        classEnd = (cltimeF.split(":"))
                        del classEnd[-1]
                        endtime = ( str(classEnd[0]) + str(classEnd[1]) )

                        for times in timeConstraint:
                            if times[2] == day:
                                if ((int(starttime) + 400) < (int(times[0])) or (int(endtime) + 400) > (int(times[1])+1200)):
                                    overlap = True
                        if not overlap: 
                            SectionMeetingTimes.append([starttime,endtime,day,condencedClassDic[classToAdd][classSection]["title"],condencedClassDic[classToAdd][classSection]["section"]])
                    if SectionMeetingTimes:
                        ClassTimes.append(SectionMeetingTimes)

            AllClasses.append(ClassTimes)

        start = time.time()

        # Save time and space by getting rid of all duplicates from the list of classes.
        sortedAllClasses = []
        for section in AllClasses:
            section.sort()
            sortedAllClasses.append( list(section for section,_ in itertools.groupby(section)) )
        sortedAllClassList = []
        for section in sortedAllClasses:
            sortedAllClassTimes = []
            for times in section:
                times.sort()
                sortedAllClassTimes.append( list(times for times,_ in itertools.groupby(times)) )
            sortedAllClassList.append(sortedAllClassTimes)

        # Calculate how many possible schedules there are.
        possibilities = 1
        for title in sortedAllClassList:
            possibilities = possibilities* len(title)

        # Make sure there aren't too many schedules to go through, set limit to about how long it takes to go through 6 minutes of possible schedules.
        if possibilities <= 1959552:
            PossibleSchedules = list((list(tup) for tup in itertools.product(*sortedAllClassList))) # List of all possible schedules generates a lot of schedules.


            '''
            startTime1 = time.time()    

            TruePossibleSchedules = []
            for schedule in range(0, len(PossibleSchedules)):  # Goes through the massive list of schedules at about 10000 per second.

                overlapping = [[s,e] for s in PossibleSchedules[schedule] for x in s for e in PossibleSchedules[schedule] for y in e  if s is not e and x[2]==y[2] and (int(x[0])<=int(y[1]) and int(x[1])>=int(y[0]))]

                good = True
                if overlapping:
                    good = False
                if good:
                    TruePossibleSchedules.append(PossibleSchedules[schedule])
                print "Iterations left: " + str(len(PossibleSchedules) - schedule - 1)

            TruePossibleSchedules.sort()
            sortedTruePossibleSchedules = list(TruePossibleSchedules for TruePossibleSchedules,_ in itertools.groupby(TruePossibleSchedules))        

            end1 = time.time() - startTime1

            startTime1 = time.time()
            '''

            #Takes a while:

            cores = mp.cpu_count()

            splitSchedules = chunkify(PossibleSchedules, cores)
            splitSchedules[0].append("First")

            pool = mp.Pool(processes=cores)
            result = pool.map(removeOverlaps, splitSchedules)

            TruePossibleSchedules = []
            for x in range(len(result)):
                TruePossibleSchedules = TruePossibleSchedules + result[x]

            TruePossibleSchedules.sort()
            sortedTruePossibleSchedules = list(TruePossibleSchedules for TruePossibleSchedules,_ in itertools.groupby(TruePossibleSchedules))

            '''
            end2 = time.time() - startTime1

            print "Origional: " + str(end1)
            print "MultiPross: " + str(end2)
            print "DIff: " + str(abs(end1 - end2))
            print "MultiPross is faster by: " + str(  float("{0:.2f}".format(( (end1 - end2)/end2) *100) )) + "%" + "\n\n"
            '''

            end = time.time()
            if len(sortedTruePossibleSchedules) <= 600:

                # Turn into a list of dicts of the class sections 
                selectList = []
                for schedule in sortedTruePossibleSchedules:
                    selectDict = {}
                    for classSection in schedule:
                        selectDict[str(classSection[0][-1])] = condencedSectionListDic[str(classSection[0][-1])]
                    selectList.append(selectDict)
                print "\n\nTime to calculate and store all possible true schedules: " + str(time.time() - startSchedules)
                print "True Schedules: " + str(len(sortedTruePossibleSchedules))
                print "Possibilities: " + str(possibilities)
                return selectList
            else:
                print "That is too many ducking possibilities, it will take over 10 minutes to load the schedules, use less variable classes"
                print "Schedules: " + str(len(sortedTruePossibleSchedules))
                return "Bad"
            print "Time taken to process Possible True Schedules: " + str(end - start)
        else:
            print "That is too many ducking possibilities, it will take over 10 minutes just to run the calculations, use less variable classes"
            print "Possibilities: " + str(possibilities)
            return "Bad"
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Bye"

def chunkify(lst,n):
    return [ lst[i::n] for i in xrange(n) ]


def removeOverlaps(PossibleSchedules):

    first = False
    if PossibleSchedules[-1] == "First":
        cores = mp.cpu_count()
        print "Commandeering your %s cores..."%(cores)
        del PossibleSchedules[-1]
        first = True

    TruePossibleSchedules = []
    if first:
        for schedule in range(0, len(PossibleSchedules)):
            overlapping = [[s,e] for s in PossibleSchedules[schedule] for x in s for e in PossibleSchedules[schedule] for y in e  if s is not e and x[2]==y[2] and (int(x[0])<=int(y[1]) and int(x[1])>=int(y[0]))]

            good = True
            if overlapping:
                good = False
            if good:
                TruePossibleSchedules.append(PossibleSchedules[schedule])

            sys.stdout.write("\rCalculating real schedules: " + str( float("{0:.2f}".format(( float(schedule+1)/float(len(PossibleSchedules))) *100) )) + "%    ")
            sys.stdout.flush()

        sys.stdout.write("\rThanks for letting me borrow those      ")
        sys.stdout.flush()
    else:
        for schedule in range(0, len(PossibleSchedules)):
            overlapping = [[s,e] for s in PossibleSchedules[schedule] for x in s for e in PossibleSchedules[schedule] for y in e  if s is not e and x[2]==y[2] and (int(x[0])<=int(y[1]) and int(x[1])>=int(y[0]))]

            good = True
            if overlapping:
                good = False
            if good:
                TruePossibleSchedules.append(PossibleSchedules[schedule])

    return TruePossibleSchedules  


try:
    start = time.time()

    makeDatabase()

    end = time.time()
    print "\nTime to create database of every section of every class offered: " + str(end - start)

    #printClass("MA 123A")
    #printClass("Differential Equations")


    pickClass("Electricity & Magnetism")
    pickClass("Differential Equations")
    pickClass("CAL 103B")
    pickClass("Mechanics of Solids")
    pickClass("Engineering Design III")
    pickClass("Circuits and Systems")


    startMon = "9:00"
    endMon = "6:00"
    startTus = "9:00"
    endTus = "6:00"
    startWen = "9:00"
    endWen = "9:00"
    startThu = "9:00"
    endThu = "6:00"
    startFri = "8:00"
    endFri = "6:00"

    lucky = raw_input("\n\n\n\nAre you feeling lucky??? (Do you want to only create one schedule) ")
    if lucky.lower() == "yes" or lucky.lower() == "y" or lucky.lower() == "ya":
        isLucky = True
    else:
        isLucky = False
        mult = raw_input("\n\n\n\nWould you like to limit the number of schedules made? ")
        if mult.lower() == "yes" or mult.lower() == "y" or mult.lower() == "ya":
            isMult = True
            multNum = raw_input("\n\n\n\nHow many? ")
            try:
                int(multNum)
            except:
                print "Ummm... That's not a number, so I'll set it to 6."
                multNum = 6
                time.sleep(3)
        elif any(char.isdigit() for char in mult):
            isMult = True
            multNum = mult
            try:
                int(multNum)
            except:
                print "Ummm... That's not a number, so I'll set it to 6."
                multNum = 6
                time.sleep(3)
        else:
            isMult = False


    daytimes = [startMon,endMon,startTus,endTus,startWen,endWen,startThu,endThu,startFri,endFri]

    timeConstraint = []
    for x in range(0,10, 2):
        blah = ["M","M","T","T","W","W","R","R","F","F"]
        broken1 = daytimes[x].split(":")
        startD = broken1[0] + broken1[1]
        broken2 = daytimes[x+1].split(":")
        endD = broken2[0] + broken2[1]

        timeConstraint.append([startD,endD, blah[x]])

    '''
    pickClass("PEP 112RF")
    pickClass("Electricity & Magnetism")
    pickClass("E 126C")
    pickClass("MA 221E")
    pickClass("CAL 103B")
    pickClass("E 231J")
    pickClass("Circuits and Systems")
    '''

    '''
    start1 = time.time()

    #printSelectedClasses()
    #printDic()

    end1 = time.time()
    print "Time to create database of every section of every class offered: " + str(end - start)
    print "Time to pick classes: " + str(end1 - start1)
    '''

    combos = possibleCombos(selectedClasses)

    if combos == "Bad":
        print "\nTry giving less range for classes or pick a section definitely want to be in instead of a whole class to lower the amount of possibilities\n"
    elif isLucky and combos:
        randSchedule = []
        rando = random.randint(0, len(combos)-1)
        print "Random number: " + str(rando)
        randSchedule.append(combos[rando])
        CreateScheduleImage(randSchedule)
    elif isMult and combos:
        multSchedule = []
        randSchedule = []
        randNums = []
        while True:
            if len(randNums) == int(multNum) or len(randNums) == len(combos):
                break
            repeat = False
            rando = random.randint(0, len(combos)-1)
            for num in randNums:
                if rando == num:
                    repeat = True
            if repeat == False:
                randNums.append(rando)
        print "Random number: " + str(randNums)
        for x in randNums:
            randSchedule.append(combos[x])
        CreateScheduleImage(randSchedule)
    elif combos:
        CreateScheduleImage(combos)
    else: 
        print "\nNo combinations available\n"

    runEnd = time.time()
    print "Total run time: " + str(runEnd - runStart)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Bye"
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Related question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173107/product-iteration-while-checking-for-overlaps)

Comment: Thanks for providing the context. This is now a much more interesting Code Review question.

Comment: @Vogel612 Where did I add information from the answers? Have you actually read the answers or my question?

Comment: @Vogel612 I added more information about my question, I am looking to improve speed, so why would I A) create a new question with all of the information and the same question but updated code B) Not update my code so when people look to answer they don't have the actual code i am using so they either repeat what I have or their solution is worse than where my code currently is.

Comment: @Jake did you read the link I provided? Because it's explained there in detail. The point is that as soon as an answer is given, it's significantly **cleaner** to "freeze" the question. Any speed improvements you made on your own are an answer and any further reviews you want are a new question. You would create a new question to prevent reviews from looking stupid, because they refer to code that's not the latest code anymore

Comment: @Vogel612 I did read it, I just thought that common since would tell me that it would be silly to create the exact same question, specially since no answer actually related to my question **at all**. So Should I just copy the entire post and title and re-ask it? Also those answers do not really answer any questions I asked, thats why I didn't accept them. And 22_success basically edited the question after the first answer to steer the answers in the direction of what I am actually asking.

Comment: Our [site policy](/help/someone-answers) generally prohibits modifying the code in the question after an answer has been posted, because in our experience, it leads to very messy Q&A when there are multiple versions of the code. That said, your changes are largely independent of the recommendations in the two existing answers, so we could probably arrive at a compromise. Please edit the question so that there is _one_ version of the code to be reviewed — choose either your old code or the new code. Until then, I'm putting this question on hold as "Unclear what you are asking".

Comment: @200_success Can you clarify what you mean by "old" and "new" code? I only have one version of the code in my question, or are you referring to the comparison in speeds between using multiprocessing and not?

Comment: Just remove all mentions of any changes or performance comparisons. If you want us to look at the multiprocessing version, then just go with that.

Comment: Alright, thank you for clarifying and catching my mistake.

Comment: @200_success I had another question about this code so I created a [new question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173107/product-iteration-while-checking-for-overlaps), I just wanted to make sure I did  this correctly

Comment: The follow-up question looks good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to this answer after focusing on the other question I posted relating to this code. My thought process was that since I first make a huge list of possible schedules that then need to be iterated over and checked for overlaps, wouldn't it save a ton of time if I checked for overlaps *as* I build the list of schedules? And my thought was very very much correct!

I replaced this code:

```
PossibleSchedules = list((list(tup) for tup in itertools.product(*sortedAllClassList))) # List of all possible schedules generates a lot of schedules.

cores = mp.cpu_count()

splitSchedules = chunkify(PossibleSchedules, cores)
splitSchedules[0].append("First")
result = []
try:
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=cores)
    result = pool.map(removeOverlaps, splitSchedules)
except:
    pass
print ""
TruePossibleSchedules = []
for x in range(len(result)):
    TruePossibleSchedules = TruePossibleSchedules + result[x]

#TruePossibleSchedules = PossibleSchedules
TruePossibleSchedules.sort()
sortedTruePossibleSchedules = list(TruePossibleSchedules for TruePossibleSchedules,_ in itertools.groupby(TruePossibleSchedules))

def chunkify(lst,n):
    return [ lst[i::n] for i in xrange(n) ]


def removeOverlaps(PossibleSchedules):

    try:
        first = False
        if PossibleSchedules[-1] == "First":
            cores = mp.cpu_count()
            print "Commandeering your %s cores..."%(cores)
            del PossibleSchedules[-1]
            first = True

        listSize = len(PossibleSchedules)
        TruePossibleSchedules = []
        if first:
            for schedule in range(0,listSize):
                overlapping = [[s,e] for s in PossibleSchedules[schedule] for x in s for e in PossibleSchedules[schedule] for y in e  if s is not e and x[2]==y[2] and (int(x[0])<=int(y[1]) and int(x[1])>=int(y[0]))]

                if not overlapping:
                    TruePossibleSchedules.append(PossibleSchedules[schedule])

                sys.stdout.write("\rCalculating real schedules: " + str( float("{0:.2f}".format(( float(schedule+1)/float(listSize)) *100) )) + "%    ")
                sys.stdout.flush()

            sys.stdout.write("\rThanks for letting me borrow those      ")
            sys.stdout.flush()
        else:
            for schedule in range(0,listSize):
                overlapping = [[s,e] for s in PossibleSchedules[schedule] for x in s for e in PossibleSchedules[schedule] for y in e  if s is not e and x[2]==y[2] and (int(x[0])<=int(y[1]) and int(x[1])>=int(y[0]))]

                if not overlapping:
                    TruePossibleSchedules.append(PossibleSchedules[schedule])

        return TruePossibleSchedules  
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

With my new code:

```
PossibleSchedules = list((list(tup) for tup in product(*sortedAllClassList))) # List of all possible schedules generates a lot of schedules.
TruePossibleSchedules = PossibleSchedules
TruePossibleSchedules.sort()
sortedTruePossibleSchedules = list(TruePossibleSchedules for TruePossibleSchedules,_ in itertools.groupby(TruePossibleSchedules))


def chunkify(lst,n):
    return [ lst[i::n] for i in xrange(n) ]

def faster(result):

    results_to_delete = []
    for schedule in result:
        for classOne in schedule:
            for classTwo  in schedule:
                if classOne is not classTwo:
                    for meetingOne in classOne:
                        for meetingTwo in classTwo:
                            if meetingOne[2]==meetingTwo[2] and (int(meetingOne[0])<=int(meetingTwo[1]) and int(meetingOne[1])>=int(meetingTwo[0])):
                                results_to_delete.append(result.index(schedule))

    results_to_delete_sorted = []
    for elem in results_to_delete:
        if elem not in results_to_delete_sorted:
            results_to_delete_sorted.append(elem)

    if results_to_delete_sorted:
        for nextDelete in reversed(results_to_delete_sorted):
            del result[nextDelete]

    return result

def productSchedules(*args):
    pools = map(tuple, args)
    result = [[]]
    cores = 4
    try:
        cores = mp.cpu_count()
    except:
        cores = 4

    for pooly in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pooly]

        splitSchedules = chunkify(result, cores)
        results = []

        pool = mp.Pool(processes=cores)
        results = pool.map(faster, splitSchedules)

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        trueResults = []
        for x in range(len(results)):
            trueResults = trueResults + results[x]

        result = trueResults

        sys.stdout.write("\rCalculating real schedules: {:.2f}%    ".format(float(pools.index(pooly))/(len(pools)-1)  *100)) 

    for prod in result:

        yield tuple(prod)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ORIGIONAL:
-> python Schedule.py
Loading classes: Done        
Time to create database of every section of every class offered: 4.80000782013

Want the best schedules? n

Are you feeling lucky??? (Do you want to only create one schedule) y
Commandeering your 4 cores...
Thanks for letting me borrow those      

Time to calculate and store all possible true schedules: 340.109536171   ***
True Schedules: 1429
Possibilities: 2350080
Time taken to process Schedules: 340.096308947
Random number: 515

Estimated time to load 1 images: 0 minutes and 1.4 seconds
Loading schedules: 100.0%    

Estimated time to load 1 images: 0 minutes and 1.4 seconds
Actual time to load 1 images: 0 minutes and 1.23541712761 seconds
Diff = 0.164559030533 seconds
Error in guess = 13.32%

Total run time: 359.528627157

NEW:
-> python Schedule.py
Loading classes: Done        
Time to create database of every section of every class offered: 5.04908514023

Want the best schedules? n

Are you feeling lucky??? (Do you want to only create one schedule) n

Would you like to limit the number of schedules made? 6

Time to calculate and store all possible true schedules: 8.99596405029   ***
True Schedules: 1429
Possibilities: 2350080
Time taken to process Schedules: 8.92583394051
Random number: [650, 238, 352, 956, 57, 503]
Preparing...
Preparing...

Estimated time to load 6 images: 0 minutes and 7.97566509246 seconds
Loading schedules: 100.0%    

Estimated time to load 6 images: 0 minutes and 7.97566509246 seconds
Actual time to load 6 images: 0 minutes and 7.38800001144 seconds
Diff = 0.587633132935 seconds
Error in guess = 7.95%

Total run time: 35.5436708927
```

Which is 3680.69% faster than the original code.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Oh! My first impression is that you felt in love with dictionaries - your multilevel dictionary ClassDic (which name should be class_dic by [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008)) is something horrible!

Why?

Mainly because it so contradict the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself). The one set of the keys used completely again and again - so are they necessary? Don't they break the readability and the logic, too?

Probably would be useful first read the The [PEP 20 - The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) (or type

```
import this
```

in your Python interpreter), particularly these advice:

> Simple is better than complex.
>   Complex is better than complicated.
>   Flat is better than nested.
>   Readability counts.
>   There should be one - and preferably only one - obvious way to do it.
>   If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.

So my tip is first refactor your `ClassDic` multi-level dictionary - maybe the solution will then emerge as a miracle.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will make sure to read those articles, but the way I structured the dictionary is due to the fact that I am pulling the data off a schools database, would it be helpful if I showed all my code? (If I do ik there will be a cringfest because its not entirely "Zen" lol)

Comment: If your data are from some database, why to not show us how you read it - probably it would be better to work with records in the database than first pull them to such complicated dictionary.

Comment: I added the code so now you can see where I am getting the database from, I am also in the process of fixing a bug where the code I originally was asking about doesn't completely sort through things so hopefully I'll add that to here once I figure it out. The main reason I am using dictionaries is because the user enters a name and it is much easier in my eyes to use a dictionary for situations where there are many variables you need to juggle per name given, it just feels more organized to me, maybe I'm just weird lol.

Comment: In regards to [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008), it states:  
CapitalizedWords (or CapWords, or CamelCase -- so named because of the bumpy look of its letters ). This is also sometimes known as StudlyCaps.

Note: When using abbreviations in CapWords, capitalize all the letters of the abbreviation. Thus HTTPServerError is better than HttpServerError.

mixedCase (differs from CapitalizedWords by initial lowercase character!)

Which is how I always find more visually appealing than lower_case_with_underscores :P

Comment: @Jake - You wrote: *"... it is much easier in my eyes to use a dictionary for situations where there are many variables you need to juggle per name given ..."*. - See my new answer. It is **fundamental** to *change the structure of your data*, otherwise the majority of people will not see a sense of reading your long code.

Answer (score 0):

Compare

```
+---------+-----+---------+                           
| Name    | Age | Country |                           
+---------+-----+---------+                       +---------+-----+---------+ 
| John    | 22  | Canada  |                       | Name    | Age | Country | 
+---------+-----+---------+                       +---------+-----+---------+ 
| Name    | Age | Country |                       | John    | 22  | Canada  | 
+---------+-----+---------+         with          +---------+-----+---------+ 
| Ingrid  | 25  | Austria |                       | Ingrid  | 25  | Austria | 
+---------+-----+---------+                       +---------+-----+---------+ 
| Name    | Age | Country |                       | Natasha | 19  | Russia  |
+---------+-----+---------+                       +---------+-----+---------+
| Natasha | 19  | Russia  |
+---------+-----+---------+
```

and

```python
[
    {"Name": "John",    "Age": 22, "Country": "Canada" },
    {"Name": "Ingrid",  "Age": 25, "Country": "Austria"},
    {"Name": "Natasha", "Age": 19, "Country": "Russia" },
]
```

with

```
[
    ["Name",  "Age", "Country"],
    ["John",    22,  "Canada" ],
    ["Ingrid",  25,  "Austria"],
    ["Natasha", 19,  "Russia" ],
]
```

or - with even simplier

```
[
    ["John",    22,  "Canada" ],
    ["Ingrid",  25,  "Austria"],
    ["Natasha", 19,  "Russia" ],
]
```

(you may assign numbers to column names, as

```
Name, Age, Country = 0, 1, 2
```

and then use those names as indices for lists).

### **But why reinvent the wheel?**

I see many `import` statements in your code, but I don't see something as

```
import numpy as np
```

You work with multi-dimensional matrices in your code - and `numpy` is the right thing what you need!

Comment: I agree that this is much simpler, and I originally did consider it, but the information given by the database for each class varies because whoever created the database annoyingly didn't feel like being uniform with how they present information so the position of information varies and the amount of information varies per class as well,  I figured this is the type of situation a dictionary is best at tackling.

Comment: Since, for example, there is sometimes more that one name or time, which would be hard to handle when using indexing because being able to tell the difference between what are names and what are titles in ["John","Math",15:00] and ["John","Lucy","Math",15:00] is harder with lists compared to dicts, where no matter the index you can determine whether there are multiple teachers or other variations.

Comment: This was my thought process, maybe I wasn't thinking strait, but do you see why I went with dicts? What would storing in a list compared to a dict better? Also I do convert the dict to a sorted list for a few processes in my code so I do see the benefit of lists compared to dicts in the appropriate place.

Comment: As for numpy, I have heard of it but never really looked into it, I've always just trucked through arrays the old fashioned way, but I will definitely look into it.

Comment: Also as a kind of ironic side note, the only part of my code that takes a long time other than when images are saved is the part where I use a list to find all the possible possible schedules. I'll take a look at numpy to see if maybe it can help, but I think its just the sheer number of iterations it must go through, which is usually around 600,000 possibilities at a rate of 10,000 per second, although this may just be limited by my hardware.

Comment: Oh, your situation is unenviable, I didn't realize it. It would be probably better if you refuse such work or put some requirements for unification of provided data, but I am not able to judge if it is possible for you. My forecast is that neither you nor your customer (supervisor? emploeyer?) will be satisfied.

Comment: Lol thats a good point. Its a personal project that I am doing because my school does not provide any scheduling tools, so I am making this for me and my friends so we don't have to spend days figuring out schedules. And yeah it is pretty unbelievable what the school uses, it makes me wonder why the people that  created that database were paid to when its obvious they didn't review it at all. Hopefully I can bring this to the attention to staff who have the power to fix this but until then I guess I'll continue unorthodoxly going about this.

Comment: I pointed out what is taking the most time to process in the post, I use itertools to speed up the process of finding overlaps, do you know of any way numpy would be able to improve the speed of the calculations?

Comment: See the economic term [Sunk costs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost), and IT one [GIGO (garbage in, garbage out)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out). See how many people were eager to review your code, including myself. Be happy that your code works and forget about it. It's my best advice. Good luck with you.

Comment: And yes, learn and then use `numpy`. It is very fast by design.

Comment: Just a quick update, I did some testing and research and found that Numpy is actually quite slower than lists in respect to iteration. When converting my code to numpy I saw that the time taken went from 30 seconds to iterate through a loop, to well over 4 minutes with numpy. I researched to see if anyone else had this behavior or if I just hadn't integrated correctly, which lead me to several sources that confirmed that numpy is indeed much slower at iterating than python lists. A very well written example: [Why is a Python list faster than a Numpy array?](https://goo.gl/Uyt6sQ)

Comment: Thanks for this information - I was convinced that `numpy` is always faster. So there are situations when it isn't true. Well to know.